# ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: NullPointerException when using .png files in drawable folder in Android Studio

Tags: android, drawable

Can somebody make scense of this? The image is in the drawable folder but when I run the code I get a NullPointerException. Please help!

```
package com.battlesheep.game.models;

    import com.battlesheep.R;
    import sheep.game.Sprite;
    import sheep.graphics.Image;

public class BackgroundTile extends Sprite {
private static Image tileImage = new Image(R.drawable.backgroundtile);


public BackgroundTile(){
    super(tileImage);
}

@Override
public void update(float dt){
    super.update(dt);
}

public void setSize(float size){
    this.setScale(size,size);
}
```

}

Here is the code calling the model that makes all the problems

```
package com.battlesheep.game.view;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import com.battlesheep.game.models.BackgroundTile;
import com.battlesheep.game.models.GameBoardModel;
import com.battlesheep.game.models.GamePiece;
import sheep.game.Sprite;
import sheep.game.State;

public class GameBoardView extends State {
  Sprite sheep;
  Sprite tile;

// CONSTRUCTOR
public GameBoardView(){
    tile = new BackgroundTile();
    sheep = new GamePiece();
}
```

Here is the activity initializing the game:

```
package com.battlesheep.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import sheep.game.Game;
import com.battlesheep.game.view.GameBoardView;
import com.battlesheep.game.models.GameBoardModel;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GameBoardModel gameBoardModel = new GameBoardModel();
    GameBoardView gameBoard = new GameBoardView();
    gameBoard.setModel(gameBoardModel);

    // create game
    Game game = new Game(this, null);
    game.pushState(gameBoard);

    // view game
    setContentView(game);
}
```

}

Here is the error message:

```
   03-17 13:34:10.330    2408-2408/com.battlesheep E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No     such file or directory (2)
    03-17 13:34:10.770    2408-2408/com.battlesheep V/class     com.battlesheep.activities.LoginActivity﹕ Sending request
    03-17 13:34:10.950    2408-2408/com.battlesheep W/dalvikvm﹕ Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lcom/battlesheep/game/models/BackgroundTile;
    03-17 13:34:10.970    2408-2408/com.battlesheep W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4133b450)
    03-17 13:34:11.040    2408-2408/com.battlesheep E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.battlesheep.game.view.GameBoardView.<init>(GameBoardView.java:26)
            at com.battlesheep.activities.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5013)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2029)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2090)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at sheep.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:44)
                at com.battlesheep.game.models.BackgroundTile.<clinit (BackgroundTile.java:11)
                at com.battlesheep.game.view.GameBoardView.<init>(GameBoardView.java:26)
                at com.battlesheep.activities.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:20)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5013)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2029)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2090)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The Image class

// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
  // Implementation of methods is not available

```
package sheep.graphics;

public class Image extends sheep.graphics.SpriteView {
private android.graphics.drawable.Drawable drawable;

public Image(int i) { /* compiled code */ }

public Image(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable drawable) { /* compiled code */ }

public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, float x, float y) { /* compiled code */ }

public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, android.graphics.Matrix transformation) { /* compiled code */ }

public void update(float dt) { /* compiled code */ }

public float getWidth() { /* compiled code */ }

public float getHeight() { /* compiled code */ }

public sheep.math.BoundingBox getBoundingBox() { /* compiled code */ }
```

}

Comment: show the relevant code

Comment: What is line 44 `Image.java:44`?

Comment: I do not know, the code stops in line 25..., posted it now :)

Comment: Look @     `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at sheep.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:44`. So what is line 44 in `sheep.graphics.Image`

Comment: `private static Image tileImage = new Image(R.drawable.backgroundtile)` Passing in a resource identifier here suggests you're using resources but there's nowhere where you're supplying a valid `Context` to `Image` required to actually access the resources.

Comment: `tileImage` is null, it's the root cause. Have you spelled `backgroundtile` name correctly? case-sensitive

Comment: @nikis It's not the root cause; the code never even reaches the part where a value would be assigned to that variable (crashes on right hand side of the assignment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the `Image` in `sheep.graphics` package refers to [this](https://github.com/perry-/TDT4240/blob/master/Game/src/sheep/graphics/Image.java) or something closely related. Examining the source, you need to initialize your `Game` object before creating `Image` objects with resource id.